# Adding controls to a window at runtime

Tags: c++, windows, forms

I'm using C++ for this project (No MFC or .NET or any libraries like that). Is it possible to use VC++ 2010 Professional to add controls to a window created with CreateWindow? I can only see how to do it when using a Windows Forms Project but mine is a regular Win32 Application (WinMain entry point). What I want to add is a dialog box with a list of clickable items in it (I don't know what kind of control I would use for this)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CreateWinodw, or DialogBox to create a Window(Dialog), and when msg WM_INITWINDOW , or WM_INITDIALOG, use CreateWindow for creating controls on the window.

e.g.
CreateWindow("BUTTON",... you can add a button to the window at runtime.
More class-name look up MSDN.

And if u need a dialog, It's suggest use Dialog resource.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381003(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: A.k.a Windows API or Win32 API for your case, which is at a lower level than MFC or Windows Form and therefore much more tedious to code.

Comment: Yes, U R right, I don't like write a win32 application, I prefer WTL as an application framework(lib).